# How to create API endpoint following REST rules?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want output in following format if i search projects by customerId

```
[
  {id: "b793ca28-3732-408a-b661-d0542309f27d", projectName: "Project A"},
  {id: "35203977-c739-4033-ade0-142cac031977", projectName: "Project B"}
]
```

What should i use in my endpoint? `pathparam` or `queryparam` if i follow REST rules

**Customer class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private String id;

    private String customerName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Project> projectList;
}
```

**Project class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private String id;

    private String projectName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable=false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to go through open forums and reliable sources for the same , Check this out https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Answer (score 0):

> What should i use in my endpoint? pathparam or queryparam

Rest may not should use `pathparam` or  `queryparam`. 
In other words, You may use either `pathparam` or  `queryparam`.

```
http://yourHost/customers/{customerId} <-- this is pathparam
http://yourHost/customers?customerId=3 <-- this is queryparam
```

But I suggest **required parameter** putting `pathparam` but **Not required parameter** putting `queryparam`.

Therefore, I recommend this if `customerId` is required parameter.

```
http://yourHost/customers/{customerId}
```